# How to make a primary key start from 1000? sqlite.net xamarin android

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, sqlite.net

I need the primary key to start from 1000  .how can do it?

```
public class LoginTable
{

    [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement, Column("_Id")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    public string info { get; set; }
    public string info2 { get; set; }



}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can modify the `sqlite_sequence` table and assign whatever starting point you want. If the `LoginTable` has not been inserted into, you will need to insert a new `sqlite_sequence` record, otherwise you would need to update the existing `sqlite_sequence` record.

The `sqlite_sequence` contains just two fields (`name` and `seq`) and does not contain a primary key nor any indexes. `name` is name of your table and `seq` is the current *used* sequence number, the next insert would increment this BEFORE using it.

#### Example:

```
using (var db = new SQLiteConnection("foo.sqlite"))
{
    db.CreateTable<LoginTable>();

    db.Execute("insert into sqlite_sequence (name, seq) values (?, ?);", new object[] { "LoginTable", 999 });

    // if LoginTable records already exist, then the `sqlite_sequence` record exists for this table and you need to update it...
    //db.Execute("update sqlite_sequence set seq = ? where name = ?;", new object[] { 999, "LoginTable"});

    var login = new LoginTable { info = "info1....", info2 = "info2....." };
    db.Insert(login);
    db.Insert(login);
    db.Insert(login);
    foreach (var item in db.Table<LoginTable>())
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item.id);
    }
}
```

#### Output:

```
1000
1001
1002
```